# Can we use tablix inside tablix with different dataset in ssrs reports?

Tags: reporting-services

I am having reports with multiple sub reports and I think it causes one issue that is report taking too much time to load. so I am trying to remove that sub reports and use tablix with another dataset which will show data by Id which is get by parrent tablix. so I am trying to use tablix inside tablix with different dataset but it causes me errors. is there any way to avoid sub reports in ssrs or to improve its time of loading. If any one have solution please post.

Comment: If you can build a new dataset that collates all the data in one go then that might be an option. The other thing to do is look at which report(s)/subreport(s) is causing the problem. You don't say how many sub reports are being rendered or how much data is being processed so it could be a simple case of optimising queries. You can also look at removing datasets in subreports that supply parameter lists etc as these are most likely redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I will say that you may want to follow Alan's advice in their reply to you and see if you can make your subreports more efficient or maybe merge the queries into one Dataset.

However if this is not an option you may want to try looking into the lookup function, if there is some commonality (or you can create some) between the different Datasets you can reference another Dataset via use of an expression. It would require you to write an expression for each column however (and would be a lot more inefficient than having the one amalgamated Dataset):

```
Lookup(source_expression, destination_expression, result_expression, dataset)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-lookup-function?view=sql-server-2017